# Getting error "The add-in <Add-in Name> is trying to extend <various extensions>, but there isn't any compatible add-in defining this extension point

Tags: c#, monodevelop, visual-studio-extensions

I'm working on an extension for Visual Studio for Mac and have it working locally. When I attempt to create the extension package and install it, I get several errors that my extension doesn't properly install because it doesn't define the proper "extension points".

Errors include:
The add-in 'MyPlugin,0.1' is trying to extend '/MonoDevelop/Ide/StartupHandlers', but there isn't any compatible add-in defining this extension point.

The add-in 'MyPlugin,0.1' is trying to extend '/MonoDevelop/Ide/Commands/Edit', but there isn't any compatible add-in defining this extension point.

The add-in 'MyPlugin,0.1' is trying to extend '/MonoDevelop/Ide/MainMenu/Edit', but there isn't any compatible add-in defining this extension point.

The add-in 'MyPlugin,0.1' is trying to extend '/MonoDevelop/ProjectModel/ExtendedProperties', but there isn't any compatible add-in defining this extension point.

I understand that this is likely because I don't have my Dependencies set up correctly, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

I've looked at various articles about Dependencies and haven't found why my code isn't set up correctly.

```
[assembly: AddinDependency( "::MonoDevelop.Core", MonoDevelop.BuildInfo.Version )]
[assembly: AddinDependency( "::MonoDevelop.Ide", MonoDevelop.BuildInfo.Version )]
```

Expected: When running vstool to create the .mpack file, it should properly include all dependencies to install in Visual Studio

Actual: Errors occur when attempting to install.

Comment: Can you post a link to the generated .mpack and the source code for your addin? Apart from `/MonoDevelop/ProjectModel/ExtendedProperties`, which I cannot find, the other extension points should be defined by the MonoDevelop.Ide addin.

Comment: I found the issue. I was creating the .mpack off of my .xml and not from the .dll.

Do you know which addin I need to add as a dependency to get ExtendedProperties?

Comment: I cannot see `/MonoDevelop/ProjectModel/ExtendedProperties` anywhere. Grepping through the monodevelop source code the closest I can see is `/MonoDevelop/ProjectModel/ProjectModelExtensions`. Can you provide more information about what you are trying to do and where you found ExtendedProperties from?